# How do you plot multiple functions in a do loop

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am having trouble plotting multiple functions on separate graph by using the Do loop. I have already figured out how to do it for just one fit function, but now I have to do it for 9 more fit functions.

```
m = 10;
t0IGList = {0.01, 0.01, 0.012, 0.015, 0.018, 0.022, 0.028, 0.035, 
0.042, 0.05};

SubDataFit = 
NonlinearModelFit[SubDataList[[1]], 
A/(1 + (2 (t - t0)/\[Sigma])^2) + 
B0, {{A, 0.7}, {t0, t0IGList[[1]]}, {\[Sigma], 0.006}, {B0, 7.0}},
t];

SubFitPlot = 
Plot[SubDataFit[t], {t, 0, 0.07}, ImageSize -> 500, 
FrameLabel -> {"Time (s)", "Voltage (V)"}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
PlotRange -> {7, 7.8}];

Do[{
   SubDataFit[[i]] = 
   NonlinearModelFit[SubDataList[[i]], 
   A/(1 + (2 (t - t0)/\[Sigma])^2) + 
   B0, {{A, 0.7}, {t0, t0IGList[[i]]}, {\[Sigma], 0.006}, {B0, 
   7.0}}, t];
   SubFitPlot = 
   Plot[SubDataFit[t], {t, 0, 0.07}, ImageSize -> 500, 
   FrameLabel -> {"Time (s)", "Voltage (V)"}, PlotStyle -> Red];
   Print["B = ", i, "Volts"];
   Print[SubDataPlot];}, {i, 1, m}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to plot "multiple functions on separate graph", which seems to mean you want 10 separate graphs.  If that right.  If so, you can separate out the two pieces of what you want: producing the fits in a loop and collecting them into a list, and then plotting the fitted functions. You can make your plotting function as complicated as you wish. Simple example:

```
flst = {x, x^2, x^3, Log[x]}
Plot[#, {x, 0.01, 2}] & /@ flst
```

Once you have this list of plots you can do anything your want with them (e.g., make a `GraphicsGrid`, or `Export` them, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Module. Create a function

```
    plot[i_]:=Module[{local variables for module},
    Any actions you want: fits, calculations etc. Separate them with ";";
    Plot[i-th function]].
```

Then you could use this function with different i from you range to create plots you want.